# Why must Isabelle functions have at least one argument?

Tags: isabelle

When I try to write

```
fun foo :: "nat ⇒ nat"  
where "foo = Suc"
```

Isabelle complains that "Function has no arguments". Why is this? What's wrong with a `fun` having no arguments? I know that I can change `fun` to `abbreviation` or `definition` and all is fine. But it seems a shame to spoil the uniformity of my `.thy` file, in which every other definition is declared with `fun`.

Comment: `fun` was introduced for none-trivial functions in the sense that their totality is not "obvios" (like for `primrec`) or trivial (like for `definition`). Hence there always is an argument (actually a tuple, if the function takes more than one argument) that is used to proof well-foundedness of the call graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex Krauss, the author of the present generation of `fun` and `function` in Isabelle/HOL had particular opinions about that, and probably also good formal reasons to say that a "function" really needs to have arguments.  In SML you actually have a similar situation: "constants" without arguments are defined via `val` not `fun`.

In the rare situations, where zero-argument functions are needed in Isabelle/HOL, it is sufficiently easy to use `definition [simp] "c = t` to get mostly the same result, apart from the name of the key theorems produced internally: `c_def` versus `c.simps`.

I think the main inconvenience and occasional pitfal of `function` in this respect is its exposure of the auxiliary `c_def` that is not meant to be used in applications: it unfolds the internal construction behind the function specification, not its main characterizing equation.

Comment: Thanks for drawing the connection to ML `val` vs. `fun`, that's a helpful intuition. I guess my reason for asking is because I'm more drawn to the OCaml way of doing things, where constants and functions are both defined using the same keyword: `let`.

Answer (score 2):

Since no other answer seems to be on its way, let me repeat and extend on my previous comment. In Isabelle/HOL there are three ways of defining functions:

- `definition` for non-recursive functions (which could just be seen as constants that serve as abbreviations for longer statements).
- `primrec` for primitive recursive functions (in the sense that in every recursive call there is a fixed argument where a datatype constructor is removed).
- `fun` for general recursive functions.

Both, `primrec` and `fun` expect at least one argument. For the former it is automatically checked that one of its arguments corresponds to the syntactic pattern of primitive recursion on datatypes, while for the latter the task of proving "termination" (or rather the well-foundedness of the call graph) will be delegated to the user in hard cases.

Anyway, it would of course be possible to relay `primrec` and `fun` to `definition` for easy cases without arguments, but at least to me this rather seems to obfuscate things for the user instead of clearing them up.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I agree that surreptitiously relaying parameterless `fun` definitions to the `definition` mechanism would indeed confuse users. The only sensible action, if any action is taken at all, would be to extend `fun` to allow parameterless functions (i.e. constants).